# not proper summing array and giving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100

Tags: java

i have array size of 100 that is array[100]

i am doing sum of entire array. i don't know where i am making mistake.

my code:

```
public void s(){
   // skipped portion of code
  float []array = new float[100]{1,2,3,...........100};
  sum (array);

  //skipped the portion of code
}
public void sum(float[] f){

        float sum=0;

            for(int z=1;z<=f.length;z++)
            {
                sum += f[z];
            }
            System.out.print("Ratio"+sum);

    }
```

not summing and not giving proper print out

Answer (score 1):

An array `a` in java is indexed 0 through `a.length-1` while in this cycle:

```
for(int z=1;z<=f.length;z++)
```

You access elements 1 through `f.length`. `f[f.length]` is out of bounds. Also the error is quite descriptive and should help a lot if you try to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays indexes start at 0 to length-1, so you need `for (int z=0;i<f.length;z++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java start at index `0` and end at index `array.length-1`.
You'r getting this exception because your asking for index 100 or `array.length`, which is 1 more element then the array has.

Replace:

```
for(int z=1;z<=f.length;z++)
            {
                sum += f[z];
            }
```

With:

```
for (float num : f) {
    sum += num;
}
```

This is a cleaner way of iterating over an array.

Answer (score 0):

in for loop f.length will give 100 but array is always indexed from 0 , in your case till 99 (total 100 memory).

change your for loop to  `for(int z=0;z<f.length;z++)`

Answer (score 0):

you are not defining the array in the proper way.
Use this:
float []array = {1,2,3,..,100};
or simply 
float []array = new float[100] and fill it with a for loop.
Array in Java are 0-index so your loop should go from 0 to len-1